# Delay JSX evaluation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have a function which returns JSX to some React components. I realized that I need to also include some of the state variables of those components in the JSX. Each component might need to change the JSX or the values in it (or both). See the code below.

```js
export function getDisplayBlock(a: number) {
  if (a == 1) {
    return <>{title}</>;
  } else if (a == 2) {
    return (
      <>
        {title}
        {subtitle}
      </>
    );
  } else if (a == 3) {
    return (
      <>
        <img src={companyLogo} />
        {caption}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

This doesn't work because in `getDisplayBlock` the `title`,`subtitle`,`companyLogo` and `caption` are not known.
Some workarounds I considered:

- Pass all those (`title`,`subtitle`) as another argument to the function. this requires recalling the function everytime these variables are updated
- Return a string instead of JSX and substitute the parameter values with regex, then use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
- "Hack it" (advantage here is that you call the function once to get the JSX that the component needs):

  ```js
  export function getDisplayBlock(this: any, a: number) {
    if (a == 1) {
      return () => <>{this.state.title}</>;
    } else if (a == 2) {
      return () => (
        <>
          {this.state.title}
          {this.state.subtitle}
        </>
      );
    } else {
      return () => (
        <>
          <img src={this.state.companyLogo} />
          {this.state.caption}
        </>
      );
    }
  }
  ```

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Why are these variable not known in your function? And if there are meant to change, you should use them as state

Comment: It seems strange to me that a single function renders three different components. However, you can just pass all those values as properties of an object. I.e. you just have one more parameter, which is an object with the needed properties.

Comment: @TheTisiboth they are in the state of the components calling this function

Comment: @FelixKling this is the proposed solution 1. In that case, when the client changes those values in runtime, they won't update in the JSX though!

Comment: Well, I would expect the function to be called again if any of the values change, thus generating a new element. It's no different really than your proposed third solution, except that the object is explicitly passed instead via `this`.

Comment: You updated the example with `this`, but that doesn't change the fact that `getDisplayBlock` would have to be called again whenever any of the state changes. Maybe show an example of where/how/when `getDisplayBlock` is called.

Comment: Hmm, why would it need to be called again? The idea with the 3rd one is that you call `getDisplalyBlock` once and you know which JSX to use in the component. Indeed with the first one, you need to call it everytime the parameters change.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to refresh the return value of the function without recalling it. You can checkout if something like React.Context is what you're interested in though it won't really improve the amount of calls to the rendering code and thus performance (is that the concern ?).

I don't fully understand the use case, i.e. if the parent components will always ever only render one of the jsx return values, then spread them out into separate components instead of having them in the same function.

The end result will be the same, the function will need to be recalled every time the state updates. But the code will be much cleaner.

Update per refreshed question:
If you want to control the JSX passed in, maybe rendering children in the subcomponent will work for you like so:

```
const GetDisplayBlock = props => {
    const { a } = props;
    return (
      <>
        {a == 1 ? (
          <>{props.children}</>
        ) : a == 2 ? (
          <>
            <diV>{props.children}</diV>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
          </>
        )}
      </>
    );
  };
...
```

Then in the rendering call, you may call it like so:

```
<GetDisplayBlock a={3}>
  <div>buyaka</div>
</GetDisplayBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the concern is performance as this is a simplified example :) I edited my question saying that indeed the JSX or the values of the variables in it might change - this was a mistake of me.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a suggestion to use props.children and thus decide in the parent components which children to render. See if that works.